# Why does this Regexp take 99.89% fewer steps using pcre rather than Python?

Tags: python, regex, pcre

I just built this expression within the regex101 editor but accidentally forgot to switch it to the Python flavour syntax. I'm not familiar with the differences, but figured they would be fairly minor. They are not.

`Perl/pcre` takes 99.89% fewer steps than `Python` (6,377,715 vs 6,565 steps)

https://regex101.com/r/PRwtJY/3

**Regexp:**

```
^(\d{1,3}) +((?:[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\-≠,]+ )+) +£ *((?:[\d]  {1,4}|\d)+)∑([ \d]+)?
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

### **EDIT**

The data source is a multi-line txt extracted from a PDF, resulting in a less than perfect output (you can see the [base source PDF here](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/666841/CT600-2017.pdf))

I'm trying to extract the box numbers, title, and any number that is present (filled in) for particular lines. If you check the link above you can see the full sample. *For example:*

Below is a screenshot of Regex101 showing positive matches. The topmost line match shows the box number (155), the title (Trading profits), and the number (5561).
[image: Example syntax]

**Restrictions:**

- Ideally extract the values as you see them in the [PCRE compiler](https://regex101.com/r/PRwtJY/3) - with little or no extra whitespace before or after the match - just the box number, title, and value.
- Only match if there is a number/value filled in (e.g. 5561 in the above example, hence not matching the line immediately after it - box 160, but matching box 165).
- The format changes lower down the form, and I have a separate regex for that, so ignore it.

Comment: 6,377,715 is not 99.89% more than 6,565

Comment: You need to get rid of the nested quantifiers (i.e. `((blablabla)+)*)`) which `PCRE` optimizes internally while the native `re` module does not, hence it results in catastrophic backtracking. What would you like to match, maybe we can be of any help here.

Comment: I'd suggest reading [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) for some pertinent background. (Guaranteed-fast regex algorithms were invented in the *1960s*; that their widespread use was abandoned in favor of shiny features -- largely by folks chasing parity with Perl -- is nothing short of travesty).

Comment: Thanks @avigil, got my phrasing wrong - edited.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. I'm familiar with catastrophic backtracking, and carefully constructed the expression in PCRE, which as the debugger shows has very little backtracking. However as Jan says it looks like I get way with it due to PCRE optimising it for me. Unfortunately the debugger is only available in the PCRE editor.

Comment: @Jan Got it. Going to have a stab at unrolling the nested statements (whilst still extracting the data I want). Will also update the question to include what I'm trying to match.

Comment: @Jan Edited to show what I'm trying to accomplish, for your pleasure ;-)

Comment: A thing you can do is to filter all lines that don't contain `∑`.

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, Google's re2 engine *does* appear to be very fast at evaluating this expression. `timeit.timeit(setup='import re2; txt=open("re-test.txt", "r").read()', stmt=r'''re2.search(r'(?m)^(\d{1,3}) +((?:[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\-≠,]+ )+) +£ *((?:[\d]  {1,4}|\d)+)∑([ \d]+)?', txt)''', number=10000)` returns ~1.5sec on my laptop to match against the full text file 10,000 times.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Nice. I considered python-pcre but figured that was cheating ;) Didn't know about re2, looks nice. Going to install and have a play. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposal: use the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) which supports atomic groups and possessive quantifiers. This cuts the steps needed about 50% compared to your *initial* `PCRE` expression (see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/PRwtJY/6)):

```
^
(\d{1,3})\s++
((?>[^£\n]+))£\s++
([ \d]+)(?>[^∑\n]+)∑\s++
([ \d]+)
```

---

To get this working, you could do:

```
import regex as re
rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^
    (\d{1,3})\s++
    ((?>[^£\n]+))£\s++
    ([ \d]+)(?>[^∑\n]+)∑\s++
    ([ \d]+)''', re.M | re.X)

matches = [[group.strip() for group in m.groups()] for m in rx.finditer(data)]
print(matches)
```

Which yields for the except given:

```
[['145', 'Total turnover from trade', '5    2    0  0  0', '0  0'], ['155', 'Trading profits', '5  5  6  1', '0  0'], ['165', 'Net trading profits ≠ box 155 minus box 160', '5    5  6  1', '0  0'], ['235', 'P rofits before other deductions and reliefs ≠ net sum of', '5  5  6  1', '0  0'], ['300', 'Profits before qualifying donations and group relief ≠', '5  5    6  1', '0     0'], ['315', 'Profits chargeable to Corporation Tax ≠', '5  5    6  1', '0     0'], ['475', 'Net Corporation Tax liability ≠ box 440 minus box 470', '1  0  5  6', '5  9'], ['510', 'Tax chargeable ≠ total of boxes 475, 480, 500 and 505', '1  0  5  6', '5  9'], ['525', 'Self-assessment of tax payable ≠ box 510 minus box 515', '1  0  5  6', '5  9'], ['600', 'Tax outstanding ≠', '1  0  5  6', '5  9']]
```

Comment: This works nicely! I had no idea about the newer module. Am combing through the regex right now to get my head around it (have another pattern to match in the file a little lower down, will try using the same technique). Thank you!